# Setting Flutter project: iOS and Android languages

Tags: flutter, settings, project

When I create a new Flutter project, it asks me to choose between Java/Kotlin for Android and Objective-c/Swift for iOS. But, what does this mean? Is it in case I want to write something for Android or iOS specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct. In Flutter you have the option to call into platform-specific APIs. This is especially useful if you need to access functionality that is not available in Flutter directly (e.g. accessing the keychain on iOS or the keystore on Android).

To do so you can open up a message channel which bridges the Dart world with the platform-specific world. You can use this message channel to send a message from Dart to you platform-specific code. This platform-specific code is either Java/Kotlin for Android or Objective-C/Swift for iOS, depending on your selections during the creation of the project.

More detailed information can be found in the Flutter documentation here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Just a heads up, the Flutter team and the Flutter community already wrote a lot of OSS packages and plugins that will take care of the platform-specific stuff and offer you an easy Dart API. You can search for these packages in the Pub: https://pub.dev